# Python NameError: name 'width' is not defined

Tags: python

This is my code for creating a game. When I try to run this it keeps saying name "width" is 
not defined. I am new to this so please make it simple while answering my question. Thanks :)

```
# 1 - Import library
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# 2 - Initialize the game
pygame.init()
width, height - 640, 480
screen-pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# 3 - Load Images
player - pygame.images.load("resources/images/dude.png")

# 4 - keep looping through
while 1:
    # 5 - clear the screen before drawing it again
    screen.fill(0)
    # 6 - draw the screen elements
    screen.blit(player, (100,100))
    # 7 - update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # 8 - loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check if the event is the X button
        if event.type--pygame.QUIT:
            # if it is quit the game
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo (`-` instead of `=`).

Comment: Assignments are `=`, not `-`

Comment: Possible 'width, height = 640, 480' would help?

Answer (score 2):

`width, height - 640, 480` to `width, height = 640, 480`

Answer (score 1):

you wrote - instead of =

also, dont use star import